# Unity android build closes on startup

Tags: android, debugging, unity-game-engine, build

I've got a complete unity project and I want to build it for android.
The problem is that it works in an emulator like Nox but it crashes on an actual android device.
I exported it to an android project and imported it into android studio and I'm getting the following logcat:

```
    07-19 11:56:53.762 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce W/ActivityThread: Application com.arioweb.plannerce is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
    07-19 11:56:54.693 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
    07-19 11:56:55.554 15123-15129/com.arioweb.plannerce I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
    07-19 11:56:55.704 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    07-19 11:56:55.704 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    07-19 11:56:55.904 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    07-19 11:56:56.105 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    07-19 11:56:56.305 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    07-19 11:56:56.505 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    07-19 11:56:56.705 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    07-19 11:56:56.905 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    07-19 11:56:57.106 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
    07-19 11:56:57.306 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/System.out: debugger has settled (1388)
    07-19 11:56:58.357 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/lib/libmain.so 0x421de508
    07-19 11:56:58.387 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/lib/libmain.so 0x421de508
    07-19 11:56:58.557 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Unity: splash_mode = 0 (integer)
    07-19 11:56:58.557 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Unity: useObb = False (bool)
    07-19 11:57:01.169 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Unity: onResume
    07-19 11:57:01.890 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_vc4.so

                                                                   [ 07-19 11:57:01.890 15123:15123 D/         ]
                                                                   GPU monitor inactive - could not find libgpumonitor.so [Symbol not found: ] or not enabled (debug.egl.hw.gpumonitor = 0)
    07-19 11:57:01.900 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_client: init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1
    07-19 11:57:01.900 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_client: init_window window 0x41713310, 800x480 hintTransform 0x4 do_pre 1
    07-19 11:57:01.900 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_client: init_window using gl pre-rotation, set size and transform to 480x800 0x5
    07-19 11:57:01.940 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce W/gl_server: setting initial viewport with draw 480x800 transposed
    07-19 11:57:01.940 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
    07-19 11:57:02.010 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [EGL] Attaching window :0x41851cd0
    07-19 11:57:02.010 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [EGL] Attaching window :0x41851cd0
    07-19 11:57:02.020 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    07-19 11:57:02.291 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Unity: windowFocusChanged: true
    07-19 11:57:02.701 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 2, Memory = 803mb
    07-19 11:57:02.711 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 2 big (mask: 3), 0 little (mask: 0)
    07-19 11:57:04.813 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [SHA1] 6dbe3e65b8fb090790408ecc3841c2c5a3546bec   26067612 bytes ~ lib/armeabi-v7a/libunity.so
    07-19 11:57:04.813 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [SHA1] 1cb327e865a8bed20e0f4cf8ec1c15afdfe60a69      25316 bytes ~ lib/armeabi-v7a/libmain.so
    07-19 11:57:05.103 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [SHA1] ff06c3db324c224f38c4d343d24f0864b2ed0789    3762548 bytes ~ lib/armeabi-v7a/libmono.so
    07-19 11:57:07.145 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [SHA1] 7e7686ded034be6aa68db4de880738278700526b   29804028 bytes ~ lib/x86/libunity.so
    07-19 11:57:07.145 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [SHA1] 30791d335d5c0f37184d020d4aaa6331dd3defc6       8120 bytes ~ lib/x86/libmain.so
    07-19 11:57:07.356 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [SHA1] e7bb23aa5772c3fbf93140004749c88003467024    3632348 bytes ~ lib/x86/libmono.so
    07-19 11:57:07.636 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Mono path[0] = '/mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed'
    07-19 11:57:07.636 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Mono config path = 'assets/bin/Data/Managed'
    07-19 11:57:07.896 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: PlayerConnection initialized from /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data (debug = 0)
    07-19 11:57:08.056 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55428
    07-19 11:57:08.096 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: PlayerConnection initialized unix socket : Unity-com.arioweb.plannerce
    07-19 11:57:08.326 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Multi-casting "[IP] 0.0.0.0 [Port] 55428 [Flags] 3 [Guid] 358875557 [EditorId] 710763119 [Version] 1048832 [Id] AndroidPlayer(samsung_GT-I9082@0.0.0.0) [Debug] 1" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
    07-19 11:57:08.326 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Waiting for connection from host on [0.0.0.0:55428]...
    07-19 11:57:13.381 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Timed out. Continuing without host connection.
    07-19 11:57:13.431 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,defer=y,address=0.0.0.0:56557
    07-19 11:57:14.042 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/mscorlib.dll.mdb doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/mscorlib.dll
    07-19 11:57:14.092 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/mscorlib.dll.mdb doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/mscorlib.dll
    07-19 11:57:14.773 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: InitializeScriptEngine OK (4ee1dee0)
    07-19 11:57:14.853 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [0.0.0.0:55428]
    07-19 11:57:16.184 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: PlayerInitEngineNoGraphics OK
    07-19 11:57:16.404 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [EGL] Request: ES 2.0 RGB0 000 0/0
    07-19 11:57:16.424 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [EGL] Found: ID[20] ES 2.0 RGB16 565 0/0
    07-19 11:57:16.434 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
    07-19 11:57:16.454 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [EGL] Request: ES 2.0 RGB0 000 0/0
    07-19 11:57:16.454 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [EGL] Found: ID[20] ES 2.0 RGB16 565 0/0
    07-19 11:57:16.454 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [EGL] Request: ES 2.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0
    07-19 11:57:16.464 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: [EGL] Found: ID[7] ES 2.0 RGBA32 8888 0/0
    07-19 11:57:16.464 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_client: init_window num_buffers 3 min undequeued buffers 1
    07-19 11:57:16.464 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_client: init_window window 0x41851cd0, 800x480 hintTransform 0x4 do_pre 1
    07-19 11:57:16.464 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_client: init_window using gl pre-rotation, set size and transform to 480x800 0x5
    07-19 11:57:16.484 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: ANativeWindow: (800/480) RequestedResolution: (0/0) EGLSurface: (800/480)
    07-19 11:57:16.484 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/gl_server: setting initial viewport with draw 480x800 transposed
    07-19 11:57:16.504 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Renderer: VideoCore IV HW
    07-19 11:57:16.504 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Vendor:   Broadcom
    07-19 11:57:16.504 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Version:  OpenGL ES 2.0
    07-19 11:57:16.504 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: GLES:     2
    07-19 11:57:16.504 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_depth32 GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_debug_marker 
    07-19 11:57:16.504 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: OPENGL LOG: Creating OpenGL ES 2.0 graphics device ; Context level   ; Context handle 1333388240
    07-19 11:57:16.514 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: InitializeGfxDevice OK
    07-19 11:57:16.514 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Initialize engine version: 5.4.0f3 (a6d8d714de6f)
    07-19 11:57:16.935 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: AudioManager: Selecting AudioTrack output...
    07-19 11:57:16.985 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/libc: pthread_create sched_setscheduler call failed: Operation not permitted
    07-19 11:57:17.005 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
    07-19 11:57:17.125 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Platform assembly: /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
    07-19 11:57:17.175 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file LoadedFromMemory doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll
    07-19 11:57:17.175 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Loading /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll into Unity Child Domain
    07-19 11:57:17.225 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll.mdb doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.dll
    07-19 11:57:17.545 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Platform assembly: /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harmless)
    07-19 11:57:17.575 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Loading /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
    07-19 11:57:17.596 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Platform assembly: /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
    07-19 11:57:17.616 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file LoadedFromMemory doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll
    07-19 11:57:17.616 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Loading /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
    07-19 11:57:17.626 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll.mdb doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.UI.dll
    07-19 11:57:17.646 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Platform assembly: /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.Networking.dll (this message is harmless)
    07-19 11:57:17.666 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file LoadedFromMemory doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.Networking.dll
    07-19 11:57:17.666 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Loading /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
    07-19 11:57:17.676 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.Networking.dll.mdb doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/UnityEngine.Networking.dll
    07-19 11:57:17.726 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: - Completed reload, in  0.717 seconds
    07-19 11:57:17.866 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Platform assembly: /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)
    07-19 11:57:17.886 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.Core.dll.mdb doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.Core.dll
    07-19 11:57:17.906 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Platform assembly: /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.dll (this message is harmless)
    07-19 11:57:17.956 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.dll.mdb doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.dll
    07-19 11:57:17.966 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.Core.dll.mdb doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.Core.dll
    07-19 11:57:18.016 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.dll.mdb doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.dll
    07-19 11:57:18.186 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce E/Unity: GLSL: unsupported array parameter 'unity_WorldToShadow'

                                                                  (Filename: ./Runtime/GfxDevice/opengles/GpuProgramParamsGLES.cpp Line: 246)
    07-19 11:57:18.216 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce E/Unity: GLSL: unsupported array parameter 'unity_WorldToShadow'

                                                                  (Filename: ./Runtime/GfxDevice/opengles/GpuProgramParamsGLES.cpp Line: 246)
    07-19 11:57:18.366 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce E/Unity: -------- GLSL link error: ERROR:LEX/PARSE-2 (line 38) Undefined identifier



                                                                  (Filename: ./Runtime/GfxDevice/opengles/ApiGLES.cpp Line: 685)
    07-19 11:57:18.366 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Note: Creation of internal variant of shader 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' failed.
    07-19 11:57:18.366 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: WARNING: Shader 
    07-19 11:57:18.366 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Unsupported: 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
    07-19 11:57:18.376 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: WARNING: Shader 
    07-19 11:57:18.376 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Unsupported: 'Hidden/Internal-MotionVectors' - Setting to default shader.
    07-19 11:57:18.446 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce E/Unity: GLSL: unsupported array parameter 'unity_LightColor'

                                                                  (Filename: ./Runtime/GfxDevice/opengles/GpuProgramParamsGLES.cpp Line: 246)
    07-19 11:57:18.446 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce E/Unity: GLSL: unsupported array parameter 'unity_LightPosition'

                                                                  (Filename: ./Runtime/GfxDevice/opengles/GpuProgramParamsGLES.cpp Line: 246)
    07-19 11:57:18.546 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: UUID: 7271bef49a8e2ea7 => 2d570d04e4e171fd04daca616270d8a5
    07-19 11:57:18.627 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: PlayerInitEngineGraphics OK
    07-19 11:57:18.627 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Found 11 native sensors
    07-19 11:57:18.647 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.153281 / 0.01s ; MPU-6K Accelerometer / Invensense 
    07-19 11:57:18.657 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Sensor :        Accelerometer ( 1) ; 0.153281 / 0.01s ; MPU-6K Accelerometer / Invensense 
    07-19 11:57:18.757 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Requested framebuffer: resolution[800x480], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[on], samples[1]
    07-19 11:57:18.757 15123-15259/com.arioweb.plannerce D/Unity: Created framebuffer: resolution[800x480], rgba[8/8/8/8], depth+stencil[0/0], samples[0] 
    07-19 11:57:19.227 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/ProgressBar: setProgress = 0
    07-19 11:57:19.227 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/ProgressBar: setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
    07-19 11:57:19.227 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/ProgressBar: mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
    07-19 11:57:19.267 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
    07-19 11:57:19.267 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
    07-19 11:57:19.267 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: right = 24
    07-19 11:57:19.277 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 24
    07-19 11:57:21.529 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Choreographer: Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    07-19 11:57:23.071 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Choreographer: Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    07-19 11:57:24.132 15123-15799/com.arioweb.plannerce W/mono: Symbol file /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.dll.mdb doesn't match image /mnt/asec/com.arioweb.plannerce-1/pkg.apk/assets/bin/Data/Managed/System.dll
    07-19 11:57:25.263 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Choreographer: Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    07-19 11:57:25.844 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    07-19 11:57:26.584 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    07-19 11:57:29.167 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Choreographer: Skipped 139 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    07-19 11:57:29.387 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce W/egl_server: Allocating storage 1x1 surface type 0x1
    07-19 11:57:30.138 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Choreographer: Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    07-19 11:57:30.188 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.228 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.278 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.318 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.448 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.498 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.538 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.578 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.628 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.678 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.718 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.758 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.808 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.868 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:30.979 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:31.019 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:31.059 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:31.099 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:31.149 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:31.189 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:31.329 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:31.379 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:31.419 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:32.340 15123-15123/com.arioweb.plannerce I/Choreographer: Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    07-19 11:57:32.350 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:32.350 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:32.350 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:32.360 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:32.370 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:32.370 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:32.380 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:32.380 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:32.400 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:32.400 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce W/khrn_fruit: khrn_umem_alloc failed
    07-19 11:57:32.440 15123-15731/com.arioweb.plannerce A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 15731 (UnityGfxDeviceW)
    07-19 11:57:41.279 15123-15761/com.arioweb.plannerce W/AudioTrack: releaseBuffer() track 0x4fd74928 name=0x2 disabled, restarting
```

I'm using Unity 5.4.0f3 and I have full serializer to send jason data over the net.

Comment: What screen size emulator did you test on and what screen size device are you using.

Comment: My device is Galaxy Grand i9082 with a resolution of 480×800 pixels. and the emulators setting is 720x1280 @MorrisonChang

Comment: A few thoughts: (1) you have too large original assets (textures, etc.) which may take up too much memory in your 4 year old phone. (2) Your phone only has 1Gb of memory, the unity project may be too complex for such a low end device. Have you been able to test the app on another Android device?

Comment: I set the memory of the emulator to 512mb to test whether that's the case but it still works there. well there was another phone but the hardware might have been alike (or even lower). my whole project is about 5 mb. and I want it to work on low end devices @MorrisonChang

Comment: All I can recommend is at least listing what version of Unity along with any plug-ins you've used. If you have a simple project which duplicates the failure you could always file a bug report with Unity.

Comment: I'm using Unity 5.4.0f3 and I have full serializer to send jason data over the net.@MorrisonChang